# Suffering error regarding flutter installation

Tags: android, dart

```
C:\Users\>flutter doctor

    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535], locale en-IN)
    [X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
        X Unable to locate Android SDK.
          Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
          On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
          (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
          If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
          You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

    [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    [!] Connected device
        ! No devices available

    ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Flutter cannot find the Android SDK.
Probably because the `ANDROID_HOME` variable is not set in your `PATH`.

The default path to the SDK on Windows is:
`C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

**Try to configure Flutter with the following command:**

```
flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk>
```